# Two root in system

Tags: security

In Ubuntu 20.04 i have two root record when i do:

```
getent passwd| grep root
```

i got

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/sh
```

and when I use

```
getent group| grep root
```

I got

```
root:x:0:
root:x:0:
```

Do I understand correctly that, this is due to the fact that this machine has an LDAP server and nsswitch.conf contains:

passwd: files systemd
group: files systemd

And is it  enough to remove "systemd" to remove this anamaly And the presence of two "root" does not mean hacking the system?

Note after clarifying questions  "FedonKadifeli" and "Raffa":

There is only one "root" entry in the /etc/passwd and /etc/group files. I did an experiment, removed the "systemd" entry in the /etc/nsswitch.conf file, leaving:

```
passwd: files 
group: files
```

and get one record for
`getent passwd| grep root`:

`root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash`

and one record for
`getent group| grep root`:

`root:x:0:0`

Comment: What is the output of `grep root /etc/passwd`? If there are two entries in the `passwd` file, you can delete the one that contains `/bin/sh` using the command `sudo vipw`.

Comment: Mess with this stuff and you're going to break your system.

Answer (score 3):

A hacker would not benefit from adding duplicate entries like this and if a hacker had gained `sudo` access to your system, this issue would be the least of your concerns. So rest assured.

#### One probability

[`getent`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getent.1.html) will get entries from Name Service Switch libraries:

> The getent command displays entries from databases supported by the
> Name Service Switch libraries, which are configured in
> /etc/nsswitch.conf.  If one or more key arguments are provided, then
> only the entries that match the supplied keys will be displayed.
> Otherwise, if no key is provided, **all entries will be displayed**
> (unless the database does not support enumeration).

So yes `getent` will query whatever database reachable from [`/etc/nsswitch.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html) including `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` referred to by **`files`** as well as probably `LDAP` and other services referred to by **`systemd`** ( provided through systemd's [Varlink](https://systemd.io/USER_GROUP_API/) and [nss-systemd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/man8/nss-systemd.8.html) ) and show all the results from all databases.

It is worth mentioning that the nss-systemd module also ensures that the root and nobody users and groups (i.e. the users/groups with the UIDs/GIDs 0 and 65534) remain resolvable at all times, even if they aren't listed
in /etc/passwd or /etc/group, or if these files are missing.

#### Another probability

Another explanation is simply that you have two entries for the same user with different user shells in *the password file* [`/etc/passwd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/man5/passwd.5.html):

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/sh
```

And two duplicate identical entries in *the user group file* [`/etc/group`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/man5/group.5.html):

```
root:x:0:
root:x:0:
```

Duplicate entries are not normal but can happen... for example due to trying to change the user shell by following some guide on the Internet and copy paste while a similar entry is already existent ( very possible with common user names like root ) or it can be added by running scripts that modify `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` with `sudo` privilege.

While your system might work normally with duplicate entries in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` ie. reading the first entry and ignoring the duplicates, it is better to remove duplicate lines ( please read about it first and make sure you back the files up before fixing and use [vipw / vigr](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/man8/vipw.8.html) for editing ).

Comment: I'm sorry, but you're wrong. There is only one root entry in the / etc / passwd and / etc / group files. I did an experiment, removed the _systemd_ entry in the /etc/nsswitch.conf file, leaving:
`
passwd: files systemd
group: files systemd
`
and get one record for `getent passwd| grep root`: `root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash`  and one record for `getent group| grep root`: `root:x:0:0`

Comment: @s79 Apologies... missed the `getent` part at the first time... You are very right and answer updated.